# Validate a phone number using formcontrol validators angular

Tags: regex, angular

I am trying to validate phone number in angular reactive form group input="number".
I have the following code:

```
number: new FormControl('', [Validators.pattern('[8|9]\d{7}')])
```

The number should consist of exactly 8 digits with the first digit only being an 8 or 9.
the validation check keeps failing whenever there is a valid input and only returns true when the input is empty.

The regex seems to be correct after testing it on other regex sites.

I have tried the following but not working:

```
Validators.pattern('[89]\d{7}')
Validators.pattern(new RegExp('[8|9]\d{7}'))
```

Comment: Did you try to use anchors? `^[89]\d{7}$`

Comment: Yes, I tried using ^..$ with both "new RegExp" and without. the output is the same  - returning true when input is empty.

Comment: I think it should be `new RegExp("^[89]\\d{7}$")`

Comment: new RegExp("^[89]\\d{7}$") works! Turns out the issue was with the \ and not the '. Is it an escape character problem?

Comment: In the RegExp constructor you have to double escape the backslash.